# silverlight crossdomain issue in https

Tags: wcf, silverlight, httphandler

my silverlight site is running in https port, when i try to access some handler in my site it searches for crossdomain.xml and clientaccesspoliy.xaml

the problem is it always searches crossdomain in https://ipaddress//crossdomaim.xml

so when i debug with fiddler it shows HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found.

client accesspolicy.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<access-policy>
  <cross-domain-access>
    <policy>
      <allow-from http-request-headers="*">
        <domain uri="*"/>
      </allow-from>
      <grant-to>
        <resource path="/" include-subpaths="true"/>
      </grant-to>
    </policy>
  </cross-domain-access>
</access-policy>
```

crossdomain.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
    <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="SOAPAction,Content-Type"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Answer (score 2):

First, get rid of the crossdomain.xml file as you only need clientaccesspolicy.xml for Silverlight (and it has more features).

Second, the file must be in the root of the https site, as that is *not* the same as the http site (I assume you have placed the file on your http site only). You need in on both sites if both the http and https sites are accessed by your app.

Thirdly, if you are still having problems, add https explicitly to the config. e.g. with

```
 <allow-from>
      <domain uri="http://*">
      <domain uri="https://*">
 </allow-from>)
```

This page on [Network Security Access Restrictions in Silverlight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645032%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) has more detail of the options

Comment: +1 Adding https explicitly is what helped me resolve the similar problems I was having a couple of years back. This article by Tim Heuer is what got me started in the right direction: http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2008/10/14/calling-secure-services-with-silverlight-2-ssl-https.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try This crossdomain.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM 
"http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
      <cross-domain-policy>
     <!--<allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="SOAPAction,Content-                 Type"/>-->    
    <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*"/>
     </cross-domain-policy>
```

Comment: Note: `crossdomain.xml` is for backward compatibility with Flash access to a site etc and you should use a `clientaccesspolicy.xml` file instead as it has more features.